# How to design rendering a new user interface for the quiz engine

Tags: android, ipad, architecture

We have a quiz application ( which is capable of rendering a question bank via traditional web browsers for question types like multiple choice, multiple response, true or false (note: it's a simple j2ee application which renders the content - runs on jboss seam, hibernate, mysql).

We have been asked to investigate support for rendering the quiz on mobile platforms like ipad2, android going forward. I would like to understand what would be the best way to design and support user interfaces via the web as well as the mobile platforms. Wkat kind of design choices should I make to enable this transition as well as leverage our existing investment. Appreciate pointers and we are not quite familiar with these mobile platforms yet.

How should I expose the question bank data which is already available in the mysql database. Should I provider JSON or REST based interfaces on the server side, which can be used by the application on the mobile platform. What kind of design / architectural patterns are available to enable such support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with just providing a web interface tailored to the mobile platform. The advantages of this are:

1. you've already got such a system implemented.
2. You don't have to store the answers to the questions on the device.
3. You can instantly support other platforms as and when they're developed (albeit with a bit of tailoring).